# Getting XML-compliant result from Solr nested arrays

Tags: xml, xslt, solr

I got an interesting case - my Solr index is based on table that contains array in another array.

Now  I need to extract data from index, in XML format.

There's no problem with XML when you're selecting data from an array, but when you get another array inside first one, your XML result becomes invalid.

There's structure of simple array:

```
orgdata array <struct <fs_form_num:string, fs_unit:string, fs_value:string>>
```

Query result becomes pretty XML with valid structure:

```
<str name="orgdata">
<item fs_form_num="2" fs_unit="lb" fs_value="100"/>
```

And there's my current problem (simplified):

```
orgdata array <struct< fs_form_num:string, formdata:array<struct<fs_unit:string>>>>
```

And result XML in this case is not so well-formed:

```
<str name="orgdata"> <item fs_form_num="2" formdata="<item fs_unit="lb" fs_value="100"/>" />
```

As you can see,

```
<str name="orgdata"> <item fs_form_num="2" formdata="<item fs_unit="lb" fs_value="100"/>" />
```

is not a valid XML structure.

Am I doing something wrong, or it (Solr) works as intended, and I have to manually transform that nested item structure to something correct (via XSL or Apache Camel)?

**Edit:**

I pinpointed my problem - I can't properly unescape this one -

```
<str name="orgdata">&lt;item fs_form_num="2" formdata="&lt;item fs_unit="lb" /&gt;&lt;item fs_unit="ton" /&gt;" /&gt;</str>
```

because I have no idea how to unescape first array without unescaping second one, like this:

```
<str name="orgdata"><item fs_form_num="2" formdata="&lt;item fs_unit="lb" /&gt;&lt;item fs_unit="ton" /&gt;"/></str>
```

Comment: My guess is that the XML structure returned actually is correct - i.e. the content is escaped properly. Have you looked at the _source_ returned from Solr, and not how it's being displayed? There is nothing illegal in XML of having the representations of `<` and `>`, escaped, inside another element or set of attributes.

Comment: Thought so, but I'm getting   "Not well formed: The value of attribute "formdata" associated with an element type "item" must not contain the '<' character"  error during XML validation.